# Adding multiple images to a matplotlib subplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make a matplottlib plot using some image data I have in numpy format, and was wondering if someone would be able to advise me on the best way to approach displaying multiples of these images within the boundaries of one subplot?

For example, using the following code...

```
n_samples = 10
sample_imgs, min_index = visualise_n_way(n_samples)

print(min_index)
print(sample_imgs.shape)
print(sample_imgs[0].shape)
print(x_train_w)
print(x_train_h)

img_matrix = []
for index in range(1, len(sample_imgs)):
    img_matrix.append(np.reshape(sample_imgs[index], (x_train_w, x_train_h)))

img_matrix = np.asarray(img_matrix)
img_matrix = np.vstack(img_matrix)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize = (10, 12))
f.tight_layout()
ax[0].imshow(np.reshape(sample_imgs[0], (x_train_w, x_train_h)),vmin=0, vmax=1,cmap='Greys')
ax[0].set_title("Test Image")
ax[1].imshow(img_matrix ,vmin=0, vmax=1,cmap='Greys')
ax[1].set_title("Support Set")
ax[2].imshow(np.reshape(sample_imgs[min_index], (x_train_w, x_train_h)),vmin=0, vmax=1,cmap='Greys')
ax[2].set_title("Image most similar to Test Image in Support Set")
```

I get the following image and output

```
1
(11, 784)
(784,)
28
28
```

[Matplotlib Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kRUC.png)

What I would like to do however is to have the second subplot, the one displaying img_matrix, to be the same size as the two either side of it, creating a grid of the images. Sort of like this
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tc2U.jpg).

I am at a loss as to how to do this however. I believe I may need to use something such as a gridspace, but I'm finding the documentation hard to follow for what I want to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make sure I understand, you'd like to take the elongated vertical image of all numbers 0-9, and plot that as a grid of numbers instead? The left and right subplots are unchanged, is that correct?

Comment: @bnaecker, thank you! Yes, that is what I wish to do. The left image is my test image which I am comparing against all of the middle images. The right image is a larger version of whichever image in the middle is most similar to the left image. This is all achieved through a siamese neural network, I just cannot display the results as I would like!